# Check is external camera available

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

is there any way to check is external camera is connected and available? I use camera2 API. CameraMetadata class have field

`public static final int LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL = 2;`

but I dont know with what value can I compare this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This it may be help to you

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
   // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.I think that this is a check if device have camera. But I am not sure that it is check if device have connected external camera .

Comment: I am getting true but hot go get Id for the external camera?